# Preventing closed Macbook from sleeping at startup

Tags: mac, laptop, macbook, sleep, clamshell

I have an old Macbook that I'm going to be tucking in a cabinet for use as a media server. It's currently running [InsomniaX](http://semaja2.net/insomniaxinfo) to keep it from sleeping when the lid is shut.

This works great when I start the Macbook with the lid open, wait for it to boot to the desktop (automatic login is enabled), then shut the lid. *It stays running.* This is good.

The problem is that when I start the laptop with the lid already closed, it boots to the desktop, but the lid detection puts the machine to sleep **before** InsomniaX has a chance to load. (Even though it's one of the Login Items for the account.)

**Is there any way, be it hackish, technical, etc. to prevent the laptop from sleeping immediately?** Even if it were to spin at the desktop for 30 seconds, it would give InsomniaX time to load.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Create a login hook](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2420) that calls a script. Let's call this script `noidle` and put it somewhere, maybe `~/noidle.sh`.

```
#!/bin/sh
pmset -a disablesleep 1
```

This script should run once and prevent sleep. To add this as a login hook, run:

```
chmod +x /Users/your-username/noidle.sh
sudo defaults write com.apple.loginwindow LoginHook /Users/your-username/noidle.sh
```

Comment: Haha unfortunately, the downside to this is that when it's run as a LoginHook, since the script never finishes, I can't actually boot into my account anymore. :) The login lifecycle seems to wait for this script to finish before continuing to the desktop, so now it just hangs at a blue screen.

Comment: Hmm. Can you try to `pmset noidle &`, that should put it into background and exit properly.

Comment: Tried that, but it looks like when it's run in the background, it doesn't actually prevent the machine from sleeping.

Comment: Ah hah! I think I got it by changing the contents of noidle.sh to `pmset -a disablesleep 1`. (Since the login hook is run as root, the `sudo` can be left off.) Woo hoo!